# How do I pass authentication tokens/headers?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have designed an authentication function that works perfectly when tested via my POSTMAN endpoint. This is what it looks like when the **Authorization** value is correct: [image: successful authorization]

And this is what it looks like when I alter the **Authorization** value to deliberately fail the authorization process:

[image: failed authorization]

Find below the authorization code:

```
const jwt = require ('jsonwebtoken');
const authenticate = (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        const decode = jwt.verify(token, 'verySecretValue')
        console.log('Authentication PASSED!');
        next();
        
    }
    catch (error) {
        
        res.json({
            message: 'Authentication FAILED!'       
        })
        
    }
}

module.exports = authenticate
```

And, now find below the code I use to render:

```
.
.
.
const authenticate = require('./authentication/authenticate.js');
.
.
.
.

app.get('/list', authenticate, async (req,res)=> {

    let countyResult = await county();
    let transId = await transactionId();
    
    transModel.find({transIndustry: 'Pharmacy'}, (err, docs)=> {
    if (!err) 
        {
            res.render('list',  {data : docs, countyName: countyResult, transId: transId}); 
        }
    else
        {
//          res.status(status).send(body);      
        }
            
    })
});
```

However, when I try to access the endpoint/link/address above via the browser, I get this error message:

```
{"message":"Authentication FAILED!"}
```

I feel like this is an **Authorization value** issue, and I don't quite know how I should be passing this value when rendering the `list` page via `res.render('list',  {data : docs, countyName: countyResult, transId: transId});`.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Is using ```res.render``` inside ```catch``` block of ```authenticate``` middleware an option ?

Answer (score 0):

You may inspect the requests that your browser makes by opening the dev tools and going to the network tab. There, you can check if the correct header is passed.

Do you have any code in the frontend to pass the token in the header?

If that's not an option, you may explore setting the token in a cookie. This way, you are sure that every request to your backend will include it.

Comment: I checked if any header is being passed in the dev tools, and cant seem to see any. 
I don't have any front end code to pass the token in the header. I am new to this, what would one look like?

Comment: I checked if any header is being passed in the dev tools, and cant seem to see any. I don't have any front end code to pass the token in the header. I am new to this, what would one look like?

Comment: Right, so in this case, there is no way for the browser to know that while making a GET request to your /list endpoint, it needs to set a header with the token.
In this case, you have 2 options to authenticate your user: session or cookie. Have a look at the examples on the express [website](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/examples.html#express-examples). The first one is about auth and uses a session